# iOS Certificates and Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

My client has a few apps in the app store that were submitted using a certain App Store profile which I have access to the account. We also have those apps installed Ad Hoc signed with the same Distribution Profile. Now I am taking care of one of this apps and I need to code sign to make a few changes and then submit it Ad Hoc for some testers. No one knows where the .developerprofile backup is. Can I revoke the existing certificate and recreate a new one without affecting the apps on the App Store. If I revoke, any other developer using this key pair will stop working, right? Any other problem I am not remembering. Can I revoke the certificate?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can safely revoke the developer and AdHoc distribution certificates without affecting any App Store apps. Be careful not to revoke any Push Notification certificates if your app uses push.

Generate a new certificate signing request on your machine and use that to generate the new certificates. Remember to edit the provisioning profiles after you create the new certificates, especially if you've added any additional devices to the provisioning list. Then download the new provisioning profiles and you should be good to go.

Any other developers (if they still have access) will be able to download the new profiles if they need them. If they also need to sign builds, they should generate their own keys/certificates as well for their developer certificates.